# Checkbuttons being all set the same tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[Gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpTHw.gif)

In my code, I am trying to create a checkbutton for each day of the week, but when I click one, they are all checked. Here is my code:

```
#reminderRepeat is a list of 7 integers
sun = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Sun", bd = 0, variable = reminderRepeat[0])
sun.pack()

mon = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Mon", bd = 0, variable = reminderRepeat[1])
mon.pack()

tue = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Tues", bd = 0, variable = reminderRepeat[2])
tue.pack()

wed = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Wed", bd = 0, variable = reminderRepeat[3])
wed.pack()
thu = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Thurs", bd = 0, variable = reminderRepeat[4])
thu.pack()

fri = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Fri", bd = 0, variable = reminderRepeat[5])
fri.pack()

sat = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text = "Sat", bd = 0, variable = reminderRepeat[6])
sat.pack()
```

They are called in a method that is called from a button.

Solution:

The problem was that I had set reminderRepeat to be a list of integers, but checkbuttons' variables are supposed to be tkinter's own data type, IntVar

For anyone wondering it used to look like this:
`reminderRepeat = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
and now I have changed it to this: `reminderRepeat = [tk.Intvar(), tk.Intvar(), tk.Intvar(), tk.Intvar(), tk.Intvar(), tk.Intvar(), tk.Intvar()]//call in tkinter loop`

Comment: How do you initialize `reminderRepeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #reminderRepeat is a list of 7 integers

The `variable` option must be given one of the special tkinter variable types.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, I had to change it to a list of IntVar()s. Thanks!